# Error: socket hang up with Node.js, Mongo DB & load-balancer

Tags: node.js, mongoose, https, load-balancing, http-proxy

I am developing an REST-API that is running via a load-balancer with a database in MongoDB.

The API works when not using the load-balancer, but when implemented i do not get a response in Postman/Insomia when posting a GET request to the database - on the index ("/") route there in no problem getting a response back though.

But as the title shows, it get this error when canceling the request in PostMan, if like the connection could not be established.

This is the full error:

```
Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:628:14)
    at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:449:25)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at net.js:675:12
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:563:7) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

**This is my load-balancer**

```
const https = require ("https");
const httpProxy = require("http-proxy");
const seaport = require("seaport");
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const HOST = 'localhost';
const path = require("path")

const PORT = 8080;

const connect = seaport.connect('localhost', 9090);

let i = - 1;

  const certificate = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert', 'key.pem')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert', 'cert.pem')),
    secure: false
};

let proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({secure: false});

let server = https.createServer(certificate, function(req, res) {

    let addresses = connect.query('server');
    if (!addresses.length) {
        res.end('Server failed');
};

i = (i + 1) % addresses.length;
let host = addresses[i].host.split(":").reverse()[0];
let port = addresses[i].port;
proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'https://' + host + ':' + port });
});

server.listen(PORT, function() {
 console.log('loadbalancer listens on'+ ":" + PORT)
});
```

**And this is my app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const morgan = require("morgan")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const seaport = require('seaport');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//Database
const db = require('./database/db');
const { MongooseDocument } = require('mongoose');

//Routes
const clientRoute = require ("./api/routes/client")
const reservationsRoute = require ("./api/routes/reservations")

app.use('/client', clientRoute);
app.use('/reservations', reservationsRoute);

//index route
app.use('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.send('Welcome to the app');
});

//Error handling 1
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error("Not found" + " ");
        error.status = 400;
            next(error);
        })
//Error handling 2
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
        res.status(error.status || 500);
            res.json({
        error: {
             message:("Error 2" + " - " + error.message )
        }
      });
    });

//Create server with the https key and certificate
const sslServer = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert', 'key.pem')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert', 'cert.pem')),
}, app);

//Middleware
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const seaportObject = seaport.connect('localhost', 9090);

//Start listening
let port = seaportObject.register('server');

sslServer.listen(port, () => {
    db.mongoConnection()
    .then(
        console.log('Localserver listens on: ' + port)
    )
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json({
            error:err,
            message: "
It went wrong here "
        })
    });
});
```

**My Database folder**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let connection;


const mongoConnection = async () => {
    if (!connection) {
        connection = 
        await mongoose.connect("removed",
       () => console.log("Mongo is up and running")),{
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
       }   
    }
    return connection;
}

module.exports = {
    mongoConnection: mongoConnection
};
```

**I am stuck on this subject, please share some guidance**

Answer (score 0):

**A solution has been found - the problem was that the database never connected**